# Impossible to Run/Compile the same project twice in a row if I don't make change in my code

Tags: delphi, delphi-10.1-berlin

I've got a weird problem when I try to Run/Compile in Delphi Berlin 10.1 Update 2 on Windows 10.

If I succeed to Run/Compile my project, and then quit the launched `.exe`, and try to Run/Compile a second time, without making any changes to my code, I get this error message:

> [dcc64 Fatal error] F2039 Impossible to create output file '.\win64\debug\eedatelier.exe'

Sometimes it says `eedatelier.rsm` instead (most of the time).

I tried deleting all `.dcu` files, same result.

I made some changes in code and saved the `.pas`, sometimes it works, sometimes it doesn't.

If I erase the `.rsm` file, it works most of the time.

Sometimes I have to erase the `.exe` file to make it Run/Compile again.

I just don't understand what is going on.

Comment: Try googling.  See f.i. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39221715/could-not-create-output-file-in-delphi-10-1-berlin

Comment: Thank you for the link. I've made a lot of change in my code before that happen, so I'm looking this way trying to find a bug I created.

Comment: As a test, try running Delphi as administrator.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/11851318/62576 Also, the .rsm file is for remote debugging symbols; if deleting it stops the problem, turn the generation of them off in Project->Options->Linker and see if that makes the problem go away. We don't know what your code looked like before you *made a lot of changes before that happen* and how it looks now, so expecting us to be able to figure out if you changed something related isn't reasonable.

Comment: I've noticed what the OP describes a few times (quite rarely). I simply rebuilt (not compiled) the project. And I would say that turning Error Insight off removed that issue (as it's been a long time I've met this problem; I've turned it off to get rid of unecessary repetitive compilation without any change in the source and no need for it). But it's just my experience as this issue was not for me so important to debug anyhow.

Comment: If the output exe cannot be created a strong candidate is that the app failed to shut correctly or is still shutting down after form closed and debugger detached. Check current processes to see if it's is still running. You may also find that in the time that you're making a bunch of futile attempts to resolve the problem, it finally finishes terminating and 'auto-corrects'. If this is the case, you'll have to figure out the flaws in your code causing the problem.

Comment: What is your project about? What is your codes doing?
did you change compiler options?

Comment: To respond some of your questions I did not change any compiler option. In win64 platform the .rsm file is generated anyway. My application is doing tasks for Car Repair Shop. One more thing when I double click on exe file directly in the compiled repertory it's always working. That's about it for now. Thank you very much for your comments!