# Delphi 2010 - [DCC Fatal Error] F2039 Could not create output file 'MyProjectName.exe'

Tags: delphi, compiler-errors, exe, delphi-2010

I'm having problems on Delphi 2010. When I try to compile I get the output below:

```
    Checking project dependencies...
    Compiling prjAlarmBlock.dproj (Debug configuration)
    [DCC Fatal Error] F2039 Could not create output file 'MyProjectName.exe'
    Failed
    Elapsed time: 00:00:00.4
```

I need to delete "MyProjectName.exe" almost every time I try to compile.
Is there a way to solve it?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Fatal Error: Cannot create output file "project1.exe"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11851318/fatal-error-cannot-create-output-file-project1-exe)