# Couldn't create output file(exe) in delphi project

Tags: windows-10, exe, delphi-7

I'm working in Windows-10 pro 64-bit.

When I run my Delphi project the smadav(2019) rev 13.2 antivirus is playing and shows the message a virus (malwez.767), has been found.
How can I fix this case?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Fatal Error: Cannot create output file "project1.exe"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11851318/fatal-error-cannot-create-output-file-project1-exe)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two possibilities:

- Either your Delphi project is a virus.
- Either your Delphi project is not a virus.

I imagine you're dealing with the second case. Then it might be a good idea to contact the virusscanner company, and ask them why this problem occurs.

Also, some virusscanners have the possibility to exclude some directories/files from the scanning. Like this, you might try to avoid your Delphi process being scanned at all.